# SQL request error because of an integer

Tags: php, postgresql, handsontable

I have a problem with a sql request (insert). I'm using handsontable to save data in my database. So here is my grid where the user enters the data. 
The row "Numéro pe" is an numeric field in the database but it's not a required field, so it can be empty !!  [image]

As I have a lot of grid like this one, I made a generic function which insert the data. So I create a string with the data like this :

```
foreach($ligne as $key => $elt)
{       
    $values .= '\''.$elt.'\',';


    if ($key == ($cptIdEssai-1))
    {
        $values .= '\''.$id_essai.'\',';
    }
}
```

And I call the function with this string in parameters and it works perfectly.

But my problem is : as my row "numéro pe" is a numeric, the request doesn't work.

Here is the warning on firebug :

> Query failed: ERREUR:  invalid syntax with the integer : «  »
>   LINE 2: ... ESSAI2','TEST ESSAI2_TRAIT1','TEST ESSAI2_BLOC1','','','');

Pb with the request:

```
INSERT INTO public.parcelle_elementaire(id_traitement,bloc,id_pe,id_essai,code_traitement,id_bloc,numero_pe,taille_pe,commentaires)
VALUES('TEST ESSAI2_TRAIT1','1','TEST ESSAI2_TRAIT1_1','TEST ESSAI2','TEST ESSAI2_TRAIT1','TEST ESSAI2_BLOC1','','','');
```

Can someone help me to resolve that please ?

**EDIT :**

So it's very hard to explain my problem but I'm going to give you more informations with more details step by step.

So :

1- The user enters the data in the grid.

2- When he submits, I send the content of this grid with Ajax and I insert the values in the database.

2.1- I make a first string with the row headers and I get exactly that string :

> id_traitement,bloc,id_pe,id_essai,code_traitement
>   ,id_bloc,numero_pe,taille_pe,commentaires

2.2- I make a second string with the data the user wrote and I get this string :

> 'TEST ESSAI2_TRAIT1','1','TEST ESSAI2_TRAIT1_1','TEST ESSAI2','TEST ESSAI2_TRAIT1'
>   ,'TEST ESSAI2_BLOC1','','',''

So, some data are empty, and it's completly normal.

3- I send this two string in a function to insert the values

```
insert($champsBase,$values,$tableBDD); //Here is my call

function update($champsDB,$idUpdate,$tableBDD,$idTable) //Here is the function
{
    $conn_string = "host=localhost port=5432 dbname=test_postgre user=postgres password='1234'";
    $dbconn = pg_connect($conn_string);

  $sql = "UPDATE public.".$tableBDD." SET ".$champsDB." WHERE '.$idTable.'='".$idUpdate."'";
$res = pg_query($sql) or die("Pb avec la requete: $sql");
```

}

4- With the variables (the two strings I made) I have this request (which is working)

> INSERT INTO
>   public.parcelle_elementaire(id_traitement,bloc,id_pe,id_essai,code_traitement
>   ,id_bloc,numero_pe,taille_pe,commentaires)
>                           VALUES('TEST ESSAI2_TRAIT1','1','TEST ESSAI2_TRAIT1_1','TEST ESSAI2','TEST ESSAI2_TRAIT1' ,'TEST
>   ESSAI2_BLOC1','','','');

But this request doesn't work because the value linked to "numero pe" is a numeric in my database and I send quotes `''`. But the value isn't a required field. That's why I don't know how to do.

Comment: What are you passing where? I don't understand anything. Echo exact query that gives an error.

Comment: if you don't want to specify the optional column, just don't. Omit it from the column list in the insert statement and don't specify a value

Comment: you say it's a numeric field but can be empty but you are passing in a string value

Comment: please give us table scheme as well... and real query that causes error, because the one you gave doesn't pass *numero pe* as number, but as string... and are you sure its `mysql`? doesn't look like `mysql` error... rather like `postgresql`

Comment: @FlashThunder  It's very hard to explain this problem, I'm gonna try to edit the post with more informations

Comment: @FlashThunder I edited

Comment: @Ronald It's a generic function, I can't omit some values or else. And maybe the user will insert this row and sometimes not. I have to specify the column :/ That is all my problem. For more explainations, I edited my post

Comment: Ok, so it is PostgreSQL not MySQL, please edit tags. Why are you trying to insert text into integer table field? Thats why you get the error.

Comment: @FlashThunder I edited tags, sorry, I didn't see :/ But I don't want to insert zero, I want to insert nothing :/

Comment: Please give a source of insert function. You need to modify that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84986/discussion-between-lison-and-flash-thunder).

Comment: Well, either render different insert statements depending on the data you have, or insert the value `null` if you don't know it. In databases `null` is that what comes closest to nothing. It looks like `insert into x (pk, optfield) values (1, null);` (table x was created with two columns, an integer `pk`and an optional integer `optfield`)

Comment: @Ronald Thanks, that's the solution. I've already done this with the help of Flash Thunder. But you're right :)